# looking for more elegant ways of rearranging digits of a number and find difference between them

Tags: python

I am trying to find a more elegant solution to sort the digits of a number (in descending and ascending orders) and find the difference between the two "sorted" (or rearranged) numbers. My code seems like *brute force* method unlike the elegant solutions I find on StackOverflow.

#This code finds if Kaprekar constant (6174) is reached for all numbers: Take any four digit number, rearrange digits in descending and ascending orders, find difference, repeat

#till the difference eventually equals 6174. (will use random numbers later instead of manual input)

```
import copy, random
n = input("type a four digit number. At least one digit must be different from rest")
while int(n) != 6174:
    nlist = []
    for i in n:
        nlist.append(int(i))
    nlist.sort()
    nasc = copy.copy(nlist)
    nlist.sort(reverse = True)
    ndsc = copy.copy(nlist)
    ndscInt = (ndsc[0]*1000 + ndsc[1]*100 + ndsc[2]*10 + ndsc[3]) 
    nascInt = (nasc[0]*1000 + nasc[1]*100 + nasc[2]*10 + nasc[3]) 
    ndiff = ndscInt - nascInt
    print(ndscInt, '-',nascInt, '=',ndiff )
    if ndiff == 6174:
        print('Kaprekar number reached')
        break
    n = str(ndiff)
    input("press Enter to continue")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this?

```py
kaprekar = 6174

def kaprgen(i, details=False):
    while i != kaprekar:
        a = ''.join(sorted(f'{i:04d}'))
        hi, lo = int(a[::-1]), int(a)
        i = hi - lo
        descr = f'{hi} - {lo}'
        yield (i, descr) if details else i
```

Note the `f'{i:04d}'` instead of `str(i)`: that way `999 -> 0999` resulting in `9990 - 999 == 8991` instead of `999 - 999 == 0` which would get stuck.

Examples:

```py
>>> list(kaprgen(1234))
[3087, 8352, 6174]

>>> list(kaprgen(1234, details=True))
[(3087, '4321 - 1234'), (8352, '8730 - 378'), (6174, '8532 - 2358')]

>>> list(kaprgen(1112, details=True))
[(999, '2111 - 1112'),
 (8991, '9990 - 999'),
 (8082, '9981 - 1899'),
 (8532, '8820 - 288'),
 (6174, '8532 - 2358')]
```

Note: if you find that some sequence is seemingly running forever without converging, you can inspect the first `n` iterations. For example:

```py
nmax = 10
>>> [v for v, _ in zip(kaprgen(1111, True), range(nmax))]
[(0, '1111 - 1111'),
 (0, '0 - 0'),
 (0, '0 - 0'),
 (0, '0 - 0'),
 (0, '0 - 0'),
 (0, '0 - 0'),
 (0, '0 - 0'),
 (0, '0 - 0'),
 (0, '0 - 0'),
 (0, '0 - 0')]
```

Using this, we can find the sequence lengths for all integers from 1000 to 9999:

```py
seqlen = {}

nmax = 10
for i in range(1000, 10000):
    len_ = len(list(zip(kaprgen(i), range(nmax))))
    seqlen[len_] = seqlen.get(len_, []) + [i]

>>> {k: len(v) for k, v in sorted(seqlen.items())}
{0: 1, 1: 356, 2: 519, 3: 2124, 4: 1124, 5: 1379, 6: 1508, 7: 1980, 10: 9}
```

The sequences `nmax`-long are the ones that got "stuck":

```py
>>> seqlen[nmax]
[1111, 2222, 3333, 4444, 5555, 6666, 7777, 8888, 9999]
```

The longest runs (7) were found for 1980 values. Let's look at some of them:

```py
>>> seqlen[7][:10]
[1004, 1005, 1006, 1024, 1025, 1026, 1035, 1040, 1042, 1050]
```

Let's try the first one:

```py
>>> list(kaprgen(1004, True))
[(4086, '4100 - 14'),
 (8172, '8640 - 468'),
 (7443, '8721 - 1278'),
 (3996, '7443 - 3447'),
 (6264, '9963 - 3699'),
 (4176, '6642 - 2466'),
 (6174, '7641 - 1467')]
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought of adding tests for 1,2, and 3 leading zeros, but with three "if. then" statements. To be honest, I am blown away by your code. Where do you work? Google/NASA/SpaceX?Thanks for replying. i can only improve by reading/practicing code like this.

Answer (score 1):

Given an integer n, you can find n1 (digits sorted in ascending order) and n2 (digits sorted in descending order) using the following snippet of code.

```
digits = [i for i in str(n)]
n1 = int(''.join(sorted(digits)))
n2 = int(''.join(sorted(digits, reverse=True)))
```